# Searching for Functions Exhibiting Semigroup Property for Energy-Efficient Neuronal Modeling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, neural-networks, semigroup-of-operators

I am working on designing energy-efficient neurons for neuromorphic computing. One of the critical aspects of the dynamics I'm exploring is that they should adhere to the semigroup property. Specifically, given a function $f$ with state $x$ and time $t$, it should satisfy:

$ f(x, t_1 + t_2) = f(f(x, t_1), t_2) $

This property is vital as, during training, I am updating the dynamics in equally-sized small timesteps, while during inference, the evolution of the state $x$ over many timesteps should be condensable into a single, cheap function evaluation. The semigroup property ensures consistent behavior between these stages.

It's worth noting that my primary concern is not biological plausibility. Instead, I aim to discover and design energy-efficient neural models. To this end:

1. I am interested in classes of functions (potentially vector-valued) that inherently satisfy the semigroup property, which I can explore through grid search or genetic algorithms to find well-performing candidates.
2. I am aware of matrix exponentiation, which offers a class of functions/differential equations that inherently possess the semigroup property. However, I am curious if there are additional classes of functions or mathematical models that exhibit this property.
3. Are there methods or techniques to construct functions (or systems of functions for multi-dimensional states) that adhere to this property?
4. Given the context of energy-efficient neural dynamics, are there any known mathematical constructs or approximations that might be suitable?

Any insights, references, or pointers on this topic would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the state space is modeled by the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Now let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $C^1$ function such that

$$ f(x, 0) = x, \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, 0) = v(x), \qquad f(x, t+s) = f(f(x, t), s) $$

for some $v : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $s, t \geq 0$. (The condition $f(x, 0) = x$ is a natural choice in light of the semigroup property.)

Then it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x, t)
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\biggr|_{s=0} f(x, t+s)
= \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\biggr|_{s=0} f(f(x, s), t) \\
&= \biggl( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\biggr|_{(x, t)} \biggr) \biggl( \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\biggr|_{(x, 0)}\biggr),
\end{align*}

where $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ are regarded as column vectors and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_d} \end{bmatrix}$ is regarded as a matrix. Simplifying the above result, it follows that $f$ solves the equation

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}v(x). \tag{1} $$

This equation can be tackled by the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Let $x : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a solution of the equation

$$ x'(t) = -v(x(t)) \tag{2} $$

Then by $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} f(x(t), t)
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}x'(t) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
= 0. $$

Hence, $t \mapsto f(x(t), t)$ is a constant function satisfying

$$ f(x(t), t) = f(x(0), 0) = x(0). $$

Let $y(s) = x(t-s)$ be the time reversal of $x(\cdot)$. Then $(2)$ and the above formula yields:

> **Observation.** For each $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $t \geq 0$, we get
> $$ f(y_0, t) = y(t), \tag{3} $$
> where $y(0) = y_0$ and $y'(s) = v(y(s))$.

The observation can be applied in reverse as well. Specifically, if we start with a continuous function $v : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, then the function $f(x, t)$ defined by $(3)$ satisfies the semigroup property. Hence, identifying functions with semigroup property is essentially the same as solving the autonomous equation $y'(s) = v(y(s))$.

Here are some thoughts:

- I notice a resemblance between $(3)$ and the [flow-based generative model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_generative_model). However, my expertise in this area is limited, so I can't conclusively determine whether they are truly related.
- From a computational standpoint, it's unclear whether this offers any benefits. Many numerical integrators for ODEs, like the Euler method or Runge-Kutta methods, construct solutions incrementally, which necessitates an iterative process spanning numerous timesteps. However, if there's an efficient method to train and compute $v$ (including its derivatives when needed), then utilizing $(3)$ could potentially be efficient as well.